# If $\lim_{n\to\infty}|\frac{a_{n+1}}{a_n}|=1$, can we also show $\lim_{n\to\infty}|\frac{a_1+\dots+a_{n+1}}{a_1+\dots+a_n}|=1$?

Tags: sequences-and-series

I think the title is true, but I don't know how to prove it.

I tried:

$|\frac{a_1+\dots+a_{n+1}}{a_1+\dots+a_n}|\le |\frac{a_1+\dots+a_n}{a_1+\dots+a_n}|+|\frac{a_{n+1}}{a_1+\dots+a_n}|=1+|\frac{a_{n+1}}{a_1+\dots+a_n}|$ and $|\frac{a_1+\dots+a_{n+1}}{a_1+\dots+a_n}|\ge |\frac{a_1+\dots+a_n}{a_1+\dots+a_n}|-|\frac{a_{n+1}}{a_1+\dots+a_n}|=1-|\frac{a_{n+1}}{a_1+\dots+a_n}|$

And if $\lim|\frac{a_{n+1}}{a_1+\dots+a_n}|=0$, the title hold, but I don't know how to show that.

Comment: You may run into problems, as the quantities you are considering might not even be well-efined. Consider $a_n = (-1)^n$, for instance.

Comment: @ClementC. Maybe restrict the question to positive sequences?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> If $\lim_{n\to\infty}|\frac{a_{n+1}}{a_n}|=1$, can we also show $\lim_{n\to\infty}|\frac{a_1+\dots+a_{n+1}}{a_1+\dots+a_n}|=1$?

I agree with Clement C's comment, but still feel that the question deserves analysis.  So, I am going to assume that $a_1, a_2, \cdots,$ are all positive real numbers.

**Preliminary result**
Given: $0 < a,b,c,d ~~$ and $~~\displaystyle \frac{a}{b} > \frac{c}{d}$. 
Then: $\displaystyle \frac{a}{b} > \frac{a+c}{b+d} > \frac{c}{d}$.
Proof:
$ad > bc$. 
Therefore, $~~ab + ad > ab + bc~~$ and
$~~ad + cd > bc + cd.$

---

Given $\epsilon > 0$, there has to be a positive integer $N$, such that

$$ \forall n \geq N, ~\left|\frac{a_{n+1}}{a_n} - 1\right| < \frac{\epsilon}{5} \implies \left(1 - \frac{\epsilon}{5}\right) < \frac{a_{n+1}}{a_n} < \left(1 + \frac{\epsilon}{5}\right).\tag1 $$

**Note:** $~~$
I chose $\displaystyle \frac{\epsilon}{5}$ as an easy way of illustrating my approach.

Let $S_n$ denote $a_1 + a_2 + \cdots + a_n$.

With $~~\epsilon > 0~~$ given, and $N$ consequently determined, my approach will be to compute $R \in \Bbb{Z^+}$ such that

$$\frac{a_{(R+N+1)}}{S_{(R+N)}} < \epsilon \implies \frac{S_{(R+N+1)}}{S_{(R+N)}} < (1 + \epsilon) \implies 
\left|\frac{S_{(R+N+1)}}{S_{(R+N)}} - 1\right| < \epsilon.\tag2 $$

Once it is established that
$~\displaystyle \frac{S_{(R+N+1)}}{S_{(R+N)}} < (1 + \epsilon) $
you will also have, by (1) above, that
$\displaystyle \left(1 - \frac{\epsilon}{5}\right) < \frac{a_{(R+N+2)}}{a_{(R+N+1)}} < \left(1 + \frac{\epsilon}{5}\right).$

Using the preliminary result, this will imply that

$$\frac{S_{(R+N+2)}}{S_{(R+N+1)}} = \frac{S_{(R+N+1)} + a_{(R+N+2)}}{S_{(R+N)} + a_{(R+N+1)}} < (1 + \epsilon).\tag3 $$

Assuming that result (2) above is established, result (3) above will imply that $n = (R+N+1)$ also satisfies the constraint in (2) above.  This process may be continued indefinitely, through the repeated use of the preliminary result.  Therefore, once result (2) above is established, you can conclude that $~\forall n \geq (R+N),~n ~$ satisfies the constraint in (2) above.

Consequently, the entire problem is reduced to establishing the existence of $~R \in \Bbb{Z^+}$ such that 
$\displaystyle \frac{a_{(R+N+1)}}{S_{(R+N)}} < \epsilon.$

---

To clarify my approach, I will derive $R$, based on what I want to accomplish.

I know that $S_{(R+N)} - S_N < S_{(R+N)}.$

Therefore, $\displaystyle \frac{1}{S_{(R+N)} - S_N} > \frac{1}{S_{(R+N)}}.$

Therefore, it is sufficient to compute $R$ such that

$$\frac{a_{(R+N+1)}}{S_{(R+N)} - S_N} < \epsilon. \tag4 $$

The way to compute $R$ so that (4) above is established is by determining a lower bound for $[S_{(R+N)} - S_N]$, in terms of $a_{(R+N+1)}$.

Let $~\displaystyle y = \frac{1}{1 + \frac{\epsilon}{5}} \implies 0 < y < 1$.

By (1) above, $\displaystyle \frac{a_{(R+N+1)}}{a_{(R+N)}} < \frac{1}{y} \implies y \times a_{(R+N+1)} < a_{(R+N)}.$

Similarly, $~y \times a_{(R+N)} < a_{(R+N-1)}, ~y \times a_{(R+N-1)} < a_{(R+N-2)}, \cdots~$.

Therefore, a lower bound for $[S_{(R+N)} - S_N]$ is

$$a_{(R+N+1)} \times \left[y + y^2 + \cdots + y^R\right]. $$

Therefore, the existence of $R$ that satisfies the constraint in (4) above may be established by showing that a value for $R$ exists such that

$$\frac{1}{y + y^2 + \cdots + y^R} < \epsilon.\tag 5 $$

$\displaystyle y + y^2 + \cdots + y^R = \frac{y(1 - y^R)}{1 - y}.$

Therefore, (5) above may be satisfied by showing that there exists $R$ such that

$$\displaystyle \frac{1 - y}{y(1 - y^R)} < \epsilon \iff 
\frac{1 - y}{y \times \epsilon} < (1 - y^R).\tag6 $$

$\displaystyle 1 - y = 1 - \frac{1}{1 + \frac{\epsilon}{5}} = \frac{1 + \frac{\epsilon}{5} - 1}{1 + \frac{\epsilon}{5}} = \frac{\frac{\epsilon}{5}}{1 + \frac{\epsilon}{5}}.$

$\displaystyle y \times \epsilon = \frac{\epsilon}{1 + \frac{\epsilon}{5}}.$

Therefore, the constraint in (6) above is represented by

$\displaystyle \frac{1}{5} < (1 - y^R).$

Since $0 < y < 1$, clearly $R$ exists such that
$\displaystyle y^R < \frac{4}{5} \implies \frac{1}{5} < (1 - y^R).$